# total number of list of delegates in this question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, solution-verification, recreational-mathematics

The question is  :
A conference is attended by 200 delegates and is held in a hall. The hall has $7$ doors labelled A,B,..G. At each door, an entry book is kept and the delegates entering through that door sign in the order in which they enter. If each delegate is free to enter any time and through any door he likes, then find the total number of different sets of seven lists would arise.

My approach:

Let $x_1,x_2,..x_7$ persons are entering into gate  A,B,C,....G gates respectively. now

$$x_1 + x_2 +..+x_7 = 200$$

total number of ways to enter $={206\choose 6}$, now the arrangement of 200 people will also count so ans is ${206\choose 6}*200!$. However I am not sure if this is correct. If I am incorrect, kindly provide alternate solution.

Comment: I find two ambiguities in the question.  One is that it talks about sets of lists, which to me indicates that you don't keep track of which list goes with each room.  Do you get a different set of lists if you swap all the people between rooms A and B?  I don't think so.  Also, does the order of names on each list matter?  That would seem indicated by the fact that the delegates sign in order of entrance.  I think it is a mess.

Comment: I agree with your answer if you keep track of which list goes with each room.  If you do that, you change weak partitions to weak compositions in my answer, which gives yours.

Comment: I didn't notice any ambiguity when I read the question. But the two answers so far have two interpretations that differ from mine! I assumed that (i) the order within a list  mattered, and (ii) the label on a list ($A,\ldots,G$) matters. Point (ii) just gives us a factor of $7!$ one way or the other, but if the order within a list doesn't matter, then the question is rather easy. So I think we should assume that is does matter.

Comment: @TonyK:  point (ii) does not just give $7!$ because of cases where two or more lists are the same length.  In the limit where all $200$ people go into the same room, it just gives a factor $7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each candidate can choose one of the seven doors. This doesn't restrict other candidates' choices. So there's a total of $7 \times 7 \ldots 7 = 7^{200}$ number of assigning candidates to doors. In this setup, the order of assignment doesn't matter, i.e. if all candidates choose door 1, the list will be $\{1:200, 2:0, \ldots  7:0\}$ (one assignment).

This comes from the fact that all doors and all candidates are unique. If the doors were unique and candidates identical, you should have used the stars-and-bars approach.

In your case, for example, the assignment $\{1:199, 2:1, \ldots  7:0\}$ can be done in 200 ways, because all candidates are different. If they were the same, that would be 1 choice.

Comment: kindly tell how you arrived at this and why my solution is incorrect

Comment: @Gingerbread pls see the edit

Comment: @RossMillikan That's not how I read the question. It seems that the order of delegates in one list is not important, but the assignment to different lists is, so A assignend to 1 and B assigned to 2 is different from B assigned to 1 and A assigned to 2.

Answer (score 2):

As I read the problem, you don't keep track of which list goes with each room because it talks about sets of lists.  It then does not matter if you swap the attendees in rooms A and B because you will get the same two lists.  You do have to keep track of the order that the people sign each list.  I don't think it is very clear.  In this reading, you can line up the people in $200!$ ways, then split them into rooms by a weak partition of $200$ into $7$ pieces.  The number of sets of lists will be the product of these two.

Comment: Even I was with the same idea.

Comment: Does this really work? If two people are on two separate lists, then which of them came first is irrelevant. I think this makes the problem harder.

Comment: @TonyK: I think it does.  You pick the partition first, which says how many people go into each room (but the rooms are unordered).  Then the list of $200$ says who it was went into each room and in what order.  If person 1 goes into one room and person 34 goes into another it doesn't tell you who went into their room first.

Comment: But then $200!$ is wrong, isn't it? For each partition of the form $p_1+\cdots+p_7=200$, we get $p_1!\ldots p_7!$

Comment: @TonyK: no, because that forces a given $p_1$ people to go into the first partition.

Comment: @RossMillikan I appreciate your idea